# LED hard-connected to battery - what is the purpose of this device?

Tags: identification

Recently, while crossing a parking lot at night, I noticed a faint light on the ground. Approaching it, I realized it's a small device loosely lying in the dirt, obviously lost by someone. There was no car or person immediately nearby, so I took it home to investigate.

The device is about 2 cm long and 1 cm in diameter. Its housing appears to be a piece of plastic that can be click-closed, but was additionally sealed, perhaps by heating and melding parts of the plastic.

On the inside, there's nothing else than a simple green LED whose electrodes are directly connected to either sides of two button batteries - unless I'm missing something there is no switch or other mechanism to turn the light on or off.

[image: device, original]

[image: device, opened]

[image: device, opened (clearer)]

What kind of device is this, and what is it used for? Also, are my observations correct?

Comment: something out of a toy perhaps ... `are my observations correct?` ... probably ... picture is not detailed enough to say anything else

Comment: Part of a toy (missing a finger strap), [like this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Original-Color-Flashing-Flashlights-Multi-color/dp/B07B954JK4).

Comment: maybe somebody is doing a study of how many people will touch an unknown object ... kind of a pointless post ... downvoting

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the innards of a light up balloon that you can find at Walmart.

Image from [here](https://www.wish.com/product/55f6806fb8e5a310be83b6fe?hide_login_modal=true&from_ad=goog_shopping&_display_country_code=NZ&_force_currency_code=NZD&pid=googleadwords_int&c=%7BcampaignId%7D&ad_cid=55f6806fb8e5a310be83b6fe&ad_cc=NZ&ad_curr=NZD&ad_price=5.00&campaign_id=9973252488&guest=true&gclid=Cj0KCQjw2or8BRCNARIsAC_ppyb1RQEIMtzKZCUdjyK5ZSvW8PsIWwu1tXAS26xSI9R40zY0nb0Lm8kaAs8_EALw_wcB&share=web)

You can see that the grey angled piece is part of a switch mechanism activated by a slide switch on the side. This is now distorted and partially on the upper half.

[image]

Comment: This looks pretty similar, especially the back part! Though the switch isn't reproducible anymore, but might have worked in a similar way.

Answer (score 2):

It seems most likely to be a ["Finger Light"](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Original-Color-Flashing-Flashlights-Multi-color/dp/B07B954JK4)  as starcat suggests.

The ones in that ad advise that they have a push on-off button and the few that I have seen have also had a switch. Due to the VERY low cost of manufacture the switch may be rather "informal" -  sometimes a sliding wedge pushes an LED lead against a battery contact.

Such lights often have no series resistor, relying on the LED voltage-current curve to set the current at a sort-of acceptable value when the battery is new and allowing the current to fall and the light to dim as the battery discharges.

[image]

---

> I think that's a plausible explanation, though I cannot find any explanation how even a simple switch would have worked.

Looking at your new photo - the light grey piece below and extending to the left of the batteries seem unnecessary for a basic "pull out tab to run once type light".

[image]

As they are aiming at minimum cost its presence suggests it is part of a switch. Examine how the LED leads make contact with the battery - I strongly suspect that moving this piece will alter how the LED lead makes contact with the battery.

Comment: I think that's a plausible explanation, though I cannot find any explanation how even a simple switch would have worked. I've added another picture with a better perspective to the question. Perhaps it's a variant without a switch altogether; some sort of give-away merchandise or similar.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach  Looking at your new photo - the light grey piece below and extending to the left of the batteries seem unnecessary for a basic pull out tab to run once type light. As they are aiming at minimum cost its presence suggests it is part of a switch. Examine how the LED leads make contact with the battery - I strongly suspect that moving this piece will alter how the LED lead makes contact with the battery.

Comment: I wasn't able to move it; all of the light-gray mold there seems to be one piece with, or at least hard-connected to the case. But there's also a chance I'm simply not able to figure out how to trigger the switch mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

It might be some kind of emergency torch.  Perhaps there was originally a plastic tab between two connections.  Pulling it out would acticate the torch.

Comment: That actually sounds plausible: There is a hole where such a plastic tab could have been pulled out. Is there a particular use for those in automobiles?